# How do I make program that can read my weekly schedule and import it to Google Calendar

Tags: android, excel, calendar, google-calendar-api, schedule

Every week I manually put my work schedule into Google Calendar. My weekly schedule is sent to my mail and opens as an Excel file with other members of my team's schedule.

Is it possible for me to write a program that, when activated would open the Excel file and copy it to my Google Calendar for me?

There are a few concerns since am/pm is not used and it isn't in 24 hour time.

I'm assuming I'll need to set parameters so the program know that `5-1` can be converted to `17:00-1:00` and `1-9` should be converted to `13:00-21:00`. While at the same time knowing that `9-5` means `9:00-17:00`. All in all it needs to treat the numbers differently based on their position i.e if it's the first number or the second.

Should I just continue putting the schedule in myself?

if not

What programming language would you suggest I use and how do I tackle the problems I listed earlier?

Please, suggestion would be appreciated, at the very least  point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to your question, but if you pick a programming language and search for "open Excel with [language]" on here you're guaranteed to find a library/API that will help you out. I'd start with Java, Python, and maybe Ruby because they all can also work with the Google Calendar API, which is here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?hl=en

You should also familiarize yourself with regular expressions if you haven't already. I'd suggest searching cells for a number-dash-number pattern, then depending on when the shift boundaries usually are, do something like:

- morning shift: if "(number between 8 and 11)-(12)", keep all numbers the same
- mid-day shift: if "(number between 8 and 11)-(number between 1 and 5)", take the second number and add 12 to it
- night shift: if "(number between 5 and 8)-(number between 1 and 6), take the first number and add 12 to it